# jquery uploadify

Tags: jquery

I want to upload multiple file with title and link. i am getting following error

invalid property id

```
$('#divUpload').uploadifySettings('scriptData',{,'txttitle1':'Title1','tbxLink1':'Link1','1':'image1.PNG'},'1');
```

My code is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">      
          var divMsg ='<%= divMsg.ClientID %>'; 
           var errcnt=0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#divUpload').uploadify({
        'uploader': WebSiteUrl + 'admin/fileupload/uploadify.swf',
        'script': WebSiteUrl + 'admin/banner-image-upload.aspx?type=fileupload',
        'multi' : 'true',
        'method' : 'POST',
        'cancelImg' : WebSiteUrl + 'admin/images/cancel.png',
        'folder': '../source/BannerImage',
        'queueSizeLimit' : '20',
        'fileDesc' : '*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.BMP',
        'fileExt': '*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.BMP',
        'wmode' : 'transparent',
        'onCancel':function(event,queueID,fileObj,data){if(data['fileCount']==0){txtboxIndex=0;$('#btnUploadfile').hide();}else{txtboxIndex=txtboxIndex-1;}},
        'onAllComplete': function(event,data) 
        {
            if(errcnt==0)
            {         
               window.opener.location.href =WebSiteUrl + 'admin/home-banner-list.aspx?mode=uploadsucc';
               window.close();
            }

        },
        'onSelect' : function(event,queueid,fileObj){$('#btnUploadfile').show();},
        'onComplete': function(event,queueID,fileObj,response,data){if(response=='maxupload')errcnt++;}})
        });
        function UploadFiles()
        {        
            var cnt='';
            var str='';
            var strLink='';

            $('.txttitle').each(function(index){                           
                 if(jQuery.trim($(this).val())=='')
                 {
                    if(cnt.length ==0)
                        cnt=(index + 1);
                    else
                        cnt=cnt + ',' +(index + 1);
                 }
            });
            if(cnt.length!=0)
            {    
                alert('Please insert title in photo#' + cnt);
                return false;
            }
            $('.txttitle').each(function(index){
                cnt= $(this).attr('name').replace('txttitle','');
                str =str + ',\'' + $(this).attr('name') + '\':\'' + $(this).val() + '\'';
                str =str + ',\'' + $('.tbxLink').attr('name') + '\':\'' + $('.tbxLink').val() + '\'';
                str= str + ',\'' + cnt + '\':\'' +  $('#hdnfile'+ cnt).val() + '\'';
            });               
            str='{' + str + '}'; 
            alert(str);           

            eval('$(\'#divUpload\').uploadifySettings(\'scriptData\',' + str +');');                        
            $('#divUpload').uploadifyUpload();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: ewww... format your code with `backticks` or the code button please

Answer (score 1):

You're generating invalid code, like this:

```
$('#divUpload').uploadifySettings('scriptData',{,'txttitle1':'Title1','tbxLink1':'Link1','1':'image1.PNG'},'1');
                                                ^ invalid comma
```

But...it's better not to use `eval()` at all, you can construct your data object with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), like this:

```
var data = {};
$('.txttitle').each(function() {
  data[this.name] = this.value;
  data[$('.tbxLink').attr('name')] = $('.tbxLink').val();
  data[cnt] = $('#hdnfile'+ this.name.replace('txttitle','')).val();
});
$('#divUpload').uploadifySettings('scriptData',data);
```

Granted that's the *literal* translation of what you're trying to do...this still isn't optimal, especially the `$('.tbxLink').attr('name')` line, since you're likely wanting the `.tbxLink` that relates to *this* `.txttitle` element you're on, but without seeing the markup I can't say exactly what that should look like.